# What is wrong with the following piece of code in prolog?

Tags: prolog

I am new to prolog and trying a very simple example on http://www.compileonline.com/execute_prolog_online.php . Here is my code:

```
:- initialization(main).
main :- 

female(ayse).
?- female(ayse).
```

But it gives an error saying that:

```
/web/com/136989421322328/main.pr:5:4: syntax error: . or operator expected after expression
1 error(s)
compilation failed
```

where line 5 is the line starts with ?. What is wrong here? Can anyone help?

Thanks.

Comment: `?-` is not a Prolog operator.

Comment: @larsmans in my notes it says that queries in prolog are prefixed by ?- so how can i make such a query?

Comment: `?-` is the interactive interpreter prompt. Use `:-` and an output predicate such as `write` (see the answer) if you're not in an interactive session.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code works:

```
:- initialization(hello).
hello :- write('hello').
```

Lines:

1. you say you want to have a predicate called hello that will be specified in the following lines that shell be executed when everything is loaded.
2. you declare the predicate.

   "hello implies write('hello') is true"

What you wanted to write is

```
:- initialization(main).
female(ayse).

main :- female(ayse), write('ayse is female').
```